# Prevent Internet access to particular user accounts... with netplan?

Tags: netplan

I just want to block Internet access in my kids' accounts.

This is possible with `iptables` (see question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/how-to-restrict-internet-access-for-a-particular-user-on-the-lan-using-iptables?noredirect=1&lq=1).

But, Ubuntu 18.04 uses `netplan`.  I've been looking, looking, looking and I can't seem find a way to do something similar on `netplan`.  Perhaps there is no such way, and the answer is to disable `netplan`.

Comment: iptables and netplan are two completely different things. I suggest that you try the iptables approach in your link and tell us if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

netplan is a management interface for configuring network interfaces (addresses, routes, and so on).  It does not handle iptables configuration, just as the tools it replaces (ifupdown) did not.